# How can I use ajax to display Bootstrap 4 modal in Rails 6 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, ruby-on-rails-6

Currently I have a modal rendering for each piece on the page. It works but I don't want to render a modal for each piece each time the page is loaded.

Here is the code where my modal is rendered now:

```
site/gallery.html.erb

<% @pieces.each_slice(3) do |pieces| %>
  <div class="row">
    <% pieces.each do |piece| %>
      <div class="col-lg-4">        
        <%= image_tag (piece.images.joins(:blob).order('active_storage_blobs.filename ASC').first if piece.images.attached?), data: { toggle: "modal", target: "#modal#{piece.id}" }, class:"img-thumbnail mx-auto d-block img-size" %>        
        <p><%= piece.name %></p>
        <p><%= piece.description %></p>
      <%= render 'site/modal', piece: piece %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Here is the modal partial:

```
site/_modal.html.erb

<div class="modal fade" id="modal<%=piece.id%>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="modalLabel"><%= piece.name %></h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        //code involving video and images for the piece
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <% if piece.quantity == 1 %>
          <%= button_to 'Purchase', checkout_create_path, method: :post, params: {id: piece.id}, remote: true, class:"btn btn-dark" %>
        <% else %>
          <p>SOLD</p>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I believe I need to do is add remote: true and pass the piece.id through my image_tag link somehow.  I think I would need a modal.js.erb with something along these lines in there

```
$('modal').html('<%= j render "site/modal", piece: @piece %>');
$('#modal<%=piece.id%>').modal('show');
```

And then render the modal at the top of the gallery.html.erb page.  I'm not quite sure how to go about this though

**EDIT**
I've made some progress with trying to use AJAX to display the modals.
I've moved my modal into the pieces directory and created a javascript file to go with it.

```
_piece_modal.html.erb

<div class="modal fade" id="piece-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      //modal content here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
piece_modal.js.erb

$('body').append('<%= j render "piece_modal", piece: @piece %>');
$('#piece-modal').modal('show');
```

In my pieces controller

```
def piece_modal
  @piece = Piece.find_by(params[:piece])
end
```

In my routes

```
get 'piece_modal' => 'pieces#piece_modal'
```

And here is the loop I'm using images to link to my modals

```
<% @pieces.each_slice(3) do |pieces| %>
  <div class="row">
    <% pieces.each do |piece| %>
      <div class="col-lg-4">
      <%= link_to piece_modal_path(piece), remote: true do %>        
        <%= image_tag (piece.images.joins(:blob).order('active_storage_blobs.filename ASC').first if piece.images.attached?), class:"img-thumbnail mx-auto d-block img-size" %>  
      <% end %>      
        <p><%= piece.name %></p>
        <p><%= piece.description %></p>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The modal displays now but it only displays images from the first piece in the loop.  How can I get it to display the correct content when I click on different images?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay I found a way for the modal to load dynamically with some ajax.

I changed up my link_to like this

```
<%= link_to piece_modal_path(piece_id: piece.id), remote: true do %>
```

I made this change in the pieces controller

```
def piece_modal
  @piece = Piece.find(params[:piece_id])
end
```

And I made this change to my `piece_modal.js.erb`

```
$('body').append('<%= j render "piece_modal", piece: @piece %>');
$('#piece-modal').modal('show'); 

$('#piece-modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
  $(this).remove();
});
```

So now instead of each piece on the site rendering it's own modal, only one gets rendered when I click on the image of the piece.  On hide though I have to remove it from the DOM or else the modal will stay rendered with the properties of the first piece I click on.

Answer (score 0):

You have written your code like:

```rb
  <%= image_tag (piece.images.joins(:blob).order('active_storage_blobs.filename ASC').first if piece.images.attached?), class:"img-thumbnail mx-auto d-block img-size" %>
```

But notice that you use `.first` which will always return the first property.

You could do something like this instead:

```rb
<% @pieces.each_slice(3) do |pieces| %>
  <div class="row">
    <% pieces.each_with_index do |piece, index| %>
      <div class="col-lg-4">
      <%= link_to piece_modal_path(piece), remote: true do %>        
        <%= image_tag (piece.images.joins(:blob).order('active_storage_blobs.filename ASC')[index] if piece.images.attached?), class:"img-thumbnail mx-auto d-block img-size" %>  
      <% end %>      
        <p><%= piece.name %></p>
        <p><%= piece.description %></p>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

p/s: I'm writing this on the fly and didn't actually test it.

Comment: Thank you for the response!  This wasn't the solution I was looking for unfortunately.  I'll post the solution I found below.

Comment: @moyejg Please I am blocked by a similar problem. Please can you share your solution? Thank you